# Cors Error for some user on hosted website

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, django, web-hosting

I have created a bot chatting website using Django and react and i have hosted this website on HOSTINGER. The backend is hosted using VPS. The problem is some of the user can see the full website and some use are getting CORS error. The API are not working for them

In the backend settings.py i have set allowed host for all and tried every possible solution i got on stackoverflow for cors but still nothing works.
if anybody has any about it please help.

i have also set all the middlewares as well.

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

i have set this to star

this is the error some user are getting but working for some.
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.heartyfi.com/open/categories/' from origin 'https://www.heartyfi.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Lots of CORS errors are possible :) If you can edit your question to include the error message, we'll have an easier time helping.

Comment: yes i have updated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up CORS settings with ALLOWED_HOSTS https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

You probably don't want `ALLOWED_HOSTS=["*"]`

If you want to enable CORS for your app, you might consider using https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/